# JSF commandButton make sure action is completed

Tags: jsf, onclick, action, commandbutton

How can i make sure that the action of this commandButton is completed, before I go to the next page?

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Edit Skin" render="@all"
                action="#{helloBean.setCurrentSkin(skin)}"
                onclick="window.location.href = 'resources/html/Editor.xhtml';" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `oncomplete` instead of `onclick`:

```
oncomplete="window.location.href = 'resources/html/Editor.xhtml'"
```

Another approach is to redirect in your action method, by just returning string:

```
return "Editor.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

Comment: Yeah I already tried that, but then I'm not going to be forwarded. Only action is executed